# How many random strings does this code generate?

Tags: perl, random, statistics, probability

I am considering this random string generator in perl:

```
sub generate_random_string {
    my $length = 12;
    my @chars = qw/2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H J K M N P Q R S T U V W X Y Z/;
    my $str = '';
    $str .= $chars[int rand @chars] for 1..$length;
    return $str;
}
```

How many unique strings will this generate?  If I extend the length of the string, how many more unique strings are available?

Also, how do I calculate the probability of generating the same string twice (assuming the length of the string stays at 12)?

Comment: Is this homework?  Kinda smells like homework.

Comment: This is not homework.  This is to settle an internal discussion over how mathematically random is "random string generation".

Comment: @Dave: you asked a completely different question than one which would help "settle an internal discussion over how mathematically random is "random string generation"".  See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY%20Problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:  (1/31) ^ 12

Or more generically:  (1/(number of characters)) ^ length

Comment: Thats 1.2e-18 or 1.2 quintillion possible strings.